# Bootstrap glyphicon proper usage?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

This doesn't work:

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" ><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
```

But this does:

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
```

My bootstrap was exctracted from bootstrap-3.3.1-dist.zip. Am I doing something wrong? I though my first usage was the most up-to-date.

Comment: The bottom example is the proper, documented implementation of Glyphicons in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons?

Comment: Oh, so I had things backwards? OK, thank you.

Comment: I've never seen the `<i class="...">` when it comes to Bootstrap, but it's possible it was from a previous version, and I've only ever worked with 3.*

Comment: ```<i class...>``` is typically in fontawsome usage, not bootstrap.